# Does only the noise ratio matter in Kalman filters?

Tags: filtering, kalman-filter, kinematics

I am working on the capture of sports movements, and in particular on X, Y, Z positions of a set of key points. Since measurements are somewhat noisy, I would like to implement a Kalman smoother with a constant acceleration process model, leveraging [filterpy](https://github.com/rlabbe/filterpy).

1. To my great surprise, it seems like it does not matter what the values of measurement noise and process noise are, *as long as the ratio does not change*. I can multiply both noises by a thousand, test it with different data, it does not make any difference.
2. Another question: results are best when my *process noise is a 100 times higher than my measurement noise*. This seems quite odd, as in most if not all examples I found, the measurement noise is much higher than the process noise.

Any input would be much appreciated, thanks in advance! [Here is my code](https://github.com/perfanalytics/pose2sim/blob/main/Pose2Sim/filter_3d.py#L53) if you need it.